# C save forked pid

Tags: c, signals, fork

Hello i have such problem

```
pid_t pid1;
pid_t pid2;

void switch_files(int sig_type)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", pid1, pid2);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t lpid1,lpid2;        
    if ((lpid1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1, switch_files);
      //Some work   
    } else {
        pid1 = lpid1;
    }
    if ((lpid2 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR2, switch_files);
        //Some work

    } else {
        pid2 = lpid2;
    }


    while(scanf("%s", input) > 0)
    {
        write(pipe1[1], input, strlen(input) + 1);
        kill(pid1, SIGUSR1);
    }

    waitpid(pid1, 0, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, 0, 0);
}
```

So i need to have value of `pid1` and `pid2` in my callback for signals, and at printf i have `0 0` but in main i have normal value of pids. How i can fix this, thank you for any help.

Comment: Does `//Some work` part include the child process exiting, or does your code fall through to running code which is meant to be run only in parent?

Comment: The second child will know the first child's pid; the first child will never know the second child's pid unless you take major steps to relay the information to the first child.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the child to have the pid, simply ask for it:

```
if ((lpid1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        pid1 = getpid();
        pid2 = -1; // other child doesn't even exist yet
        signal(SIGUSR1, switch_files);
        //Some work
        exit(0); // you don't want the child to go executing parent code, do you?
    }
```

And

```
if ((lpid2 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        //pid1 already set with pid of 1st child
        pid2 = getpid();
        signal(SIGUSR2, switch_files);
        //Some work
        exit(0); // you don't want the child to go executing parent code, do you?
    }
```

If you need to the 1st child to have the pid of the 2nd child, then you need to use [some form of IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), so you can communicate to the the 1st child after also 2nd child has been started and its pid is known.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the children to have information, you have to communicate that information to them somehow. You can use a file, a pipe, shared memory, or any mechanism you want. But you have to pass the information somehow.